# Add additional records to local Realm database in published app

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I would like to bundle a local realm database with an iOS app and publish it to the app store. The initial database will ship with about 500 data records in a table, named TableA.

Then, in an app update I would like to insert an additional 250 records to TableA.

What would be an optimal solution for this scenario?

I have thought about including a JSON file in the app update with the 250 new records, and writing the data from the JSON into the realm database. Can anyone provide feedback on this solution, or suggest a better one?

Comment: You cannot modify a bundled realm - it's read only. Same thing with the JSON - you can't modify a bundled realm. You could do one of a few things, include a new realm with your app update with all of the data, OR create a realm on disk from your bundled realm, and then *that* realm could be modified with new data.

Comment: Second that. What I would do is include a new realm with your app update. You don't have to manually populate all 250 records. You can create a separate test project, populate your realm file using code (make sure the schema versions match). Then once it's populated, just replace the old realm file in your app with the new one you populated and don't forget the migration code.

Comment: @Jay Thank you for your input. I was not aware that bundled files were read only. I like your idea of creating a new realm on disk from the bundled realm.

Comment: @rs7 I don't want to replace the realm with the update because I want keep the previously existing data. For example, if a user marks an item from TableA as a favorite, I want the favorite status to remain in the table, and just add the new 250 records with the favorite field set to null. Adding them programmatically with a test project is good.

Comment: Remember bundled realms are read only, see [Bundled](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#bundling-a-realm) #6. That means you cannot modify it. So if a user marks an item as a favorite, it cannot be in the bundled realm - it will have to be on the Realm you copied to disk. Because of that you can just appends the new data to that same file. Likewise, you could track what they selected, replace the file and re-select those in the new file.

Answer (score -1):

When user first open the app, check your condition, and then you can show a progress bar and do your job. I think it's fine.